# AngularJS ng-show - 2 Times, 2 different results

Tags: angularjs, ng-show

I am creating an app with angularjs, cordova and iconic. 
I have a trash icon which should be show only when the user is at the main page.

So i will show the icon only wenn the rootScope.Trashicon is true.

It works fine in my sidemenu. But in the side-menu-content area it doesnt work. I dont know why...

```
    <ion-side-menus ng-controller="MainController" ng-init="getListTitle()">
      <ion-side-menu side = "left"> <!-- expose-aside-when DELETE IT !!!!!! -->
          <header><img src="img/todo_today_logo_small.png"></header>
          <div id="sideContent" class="item item-divider">ToDo Liste: 
              <p>                  
                  > <a menu-close href="#/todo">{{sideMenuListTitle}}</a>
              </p>
              <div ng-show="Trashicon">test</div>
              <h3></h3>
          </div>
          <div>
              <ul>
                  <li><a menu-close href="#/impressum">Impressum</a></li>
                  <li><a menu-close href="#/datenschutzerklaerung">Datenschutzerklärung</a></li>
              </ul>
          </div>
      </ion-side-menu>

      <ion-side-menu-content>
           <ion-nav-bar class="custom-dark" align-title="center">
               <ion-nav-buttons side="left">


    <!-- Toggle left side menu -->
   <button menu-toggle="left" class="button button-icon icon ion-navicon light"></button>   
  </ion-nav-buttons>
               <div ng-show="Trashicon">
                   <ion-nav-buttons side="right">
                   <button ng-click="deleteProducts()" class="button button-icon ion-ios-trash-outline pull-right light"></button>
               </ion-nav-buttons> 
               </div>                 
         <ion-nav-title></ion-nav-title>
  </ion-nav-bar>
          <div ng-view="" class="container"></div>
      </ion-side-menu-content>
  </ion-side-menus>
```

This is my rootScope Variable

```
.controller('MainController', function ($scope, $ionicPopup, $rootScope) {
            $rootScope.Trashicon = false;
```

The div with the trash icon is still visible.. and i dont know why... it would be great if someone has an idea for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seams the element **ion-nav-buttons** has its own styling which overrides all elements above it.

If you move the **ng-show** closer the button you will have better control.

i.e instead of

```
<div ng-show="Trashicon">
    <ion-nav-buttons side="right">
        <button ng-click="deleteProducts()" class="button button-icon ion-ios-trash-outline pull-right light"></button>
    </ion-nav-buttons> 
</div>
```

do this

```
<div>
    <ion-nav-buttons side="right">
        <button ng-show="Trashicon" ng-click="deleteProducts()" class="button button-icon ion-ios-trash-outline pull-right light"></button>
    </ion-nav-buttons> 
</div>
```

Comment: Glad I could help :)  Don't forget to accept the answer!

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: You need to mark the answer as accepted.  For each answer you can vote up, vote down and if you asked the question you can accept the answer.  The answer will have a green tick next to it.

Answer (score 0):

If i try ng-show="1==2" it will work only in the side menu too....

and not in the side menu content area.. the div will show if ng-show="1==2"... strange